# Qt: setting text to a Qlabel with a pixmap and back

Tags: c++, qlabel

So i have a QLabel with a pixmap (added to it with the function setPixmap() ). Let's say now I add text to it with setText(). The QLabel starts displaying the text which is what I want it to do. And now is my question - is there a way to change the label back to start showing the previous pixmap rather than adding it again with setPixmap()?

Comment: Well you could store that pixmap to your class and reload from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#text-prop

Here is written that setting text to QLabel  clears any previous content.

Answer (score 0):

This limitation from Qt 4.8 which still appears to be there can be overcome by using:

> setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/sunset.jpg);");

For more information see:
[Unable to set the background image in Qt Stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458201/unable-to-set-the-background-image-in-qt-stylesheet)