# Background at Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I just started my first project in Qt and I have problem with setting background for my `QWidget`. I added my photo to resources of project in qrc file. After that i edited my widget stylesheets and added there:

```
background-image: url('://resources/assets/subaru.jpg');
```

Unfortunately, I see my background only in preview editor ui, after compiled background is empty, without image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set the background image in Qt Stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458201/unable-to-set-the-background-image-in-qt-stylesheet)

Comment: Everything made by answear of this question, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: have you tried passing the full path to it unrelated to the qrc

Comment: 1. Remove extra slash. 2. Be sure that qtjpg plugin is loaded. 3. Be sure that path is available at runtime `Q_ASSERT( QFileInfo( ":/path/to/image.jpg" ).isExists() );`

Comment: Q_ASSERT(QFileInfo( ":/resources/assets/subaru.jpg" ).exists() ); do nothing, so this file exist. :).

Comment: I added  QTPLUGIN += qjpeg to .pro, and  #include <QtPlugin> in main.cpp. Nothing, doesn't work. : (

Comment: If used Qt creator - are you try right-click on resource file and "Copy url: <imagepath>" and paste it to stylesheet?

Comment: Of course, that's why i have double //.