# qt background stylesheets doesn't work

Tags: c++, css, qt

I wanted to back to my problem:

[Background at Qt Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830143/background-at-qt-widget)

```
background-image: url(':/resources/assets/subaru.jpg');
```

It doesn't work. The background is just colored. When I add for example this .jpg resource as icon in PushButton it works welll. Doesn't want add as background, why? Can I set is as background in different way? I try

```
Q_ASSERT(QFileInfo( ":/resources/assets/subaru.jpg" ).exists() );
```

and program see this resource.

Comment: If you subclass a custom widget from QWidget, then in order to use the StyleSheets you need to provide a paintEvent to the custom widget

https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget

Comment: I created only qWidget, it doesn't have any parents. : (

Comment: Ok. Can you append [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I found in my project: `border-image: url(:/ico/background.jpg) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;` Maybe this?

Comment: Works only in preview...

Comment: The background-image works on every element  except QWidget....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add QGroupBox and make it as big as QWidget. It works, thanks! It holds my background.