# QDialog - setting background image

Tags: c++, qt, background-image, qdialog

How can I simply set background of my QDialog? I can easily set colour of background, but when i try use image, my background just goes black. I was trying to use: QPallete with QBrush, StyleSheets :(.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    setStyleSheet( "background-image:url(image.jpg);" ); //this works
}
```

See also: [Unable to set the background image in Qt Stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458201/unable-to-set-the-background-image-in-qt-stylesheet)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work :/ I have my .jpg in resources, path is correct and nothing changes on my background :(

Comment: @KCrookedHand - Did you deploy the imageformats folder with your app? See also [autoFillBackground](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) and [Qt Image Formats](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop)