# How to set up stylesheet in QT to choose random image for wiget background?

Tags: c++, qt, qstylesheet

So I'm trying to choose random image from file system of my pc and make it background in wiget. So thats why I'm opening QFileDialog and using it. qDebug gives me right path to the image, but still it doesn't work.

```
void ChatWindow::on_actionImage_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
        this, tr("Open file"), "/home", tr("Images(*.jpg)")
    );
    QString filePath(fileName);
    qDebug () << filePath;
    setStyleSheet(
        "ChatWindow{border-image:url(:" +
            filePath +
        ") 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}"
    );

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect * effect1 =
        new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->messageHistory);
    effect1->setOpacity(0.8);
    ui->messageHistory->setGraphicsEffect(effect1);
    ui->messageHistory->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect * effect2 =
        new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->roomTree);
    effect2->setOpacity(0.8);
    ui->roomTree->setGraphicsEffect(effect2);
    ui->roomTree->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");

    QGraphicsOpacityEffect * effect3 =
        new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->messageInput);
    effect3->setOpacity(0.8);
    ui->messageInput->setGraphicsEffect(effect3);

    ui->sendButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: none;");
}
```

I've seen this one [Unable to set the background image in Qt Stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458201/unable-to-set-the-background-image-in-qt-stylesheet) related to my problem, but in my case it doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ChatWindow{background-image:url(...)` instead of `ChatWindow{border-image:url(...)`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful I've tried to use background-image, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties), there is no such property called `border-image`: what you're searching for is `background-image`.

Moreover, since you're also specifying other background's parameters, you should use `background`.

Moreover, since your file is on the disk and not in the resources, the url should not start with `:`: type `url(" + filePath + ")` instead of `url(:" + filePath + ")`.

The corrected syntax:

```
setStyleSheet(
    "ChatWindow{background:url(" +
        filePath +
    ") 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}"
);
```

Comment: thank you, now it works. Next time i'll read documentation more carefully.